# Linux: Stop monitoring tools when a process has terminated

Tags: linux, bash, performance, monitoring, benchmarking

I have to launch some benchmarks on Linux and monitor them through some monitoring tools, including vmstat and iostat.
The benchmarks are going to execute for some hours, so I want to automate the monitoring process, executing (for example) vmstat every X seconds until the benchmarks finish its work, so that it doesn't continue indefinitely until is not me to kill it manually. 
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Run `vmstat 5` in the background to have it print every 5 seconds.

Record its PID and kill it after the benchmark is done.

```
vmstat 5 > vmstat.log &
pid_of_vmstat=$!

run_benchmark

kill "$pid_of_vmstat"
```

Not tested, read the bash man page if any of that doesn't work.